# iOS 13 SDK deadline confusion for existing released apps

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm confused by Apple's latest email regarding their requirements for apps to use iOS SDK 13.

So first there was this message March 4th:

[Submit Your iPhone Apps to the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03042020b)

> Starting April 30, 2020, all iPhone apps **submitted** to the App Store must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later.

Then they send out this message on March 26th:

[Deadline for App Updates has Been Extended](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03262020b)

> To accommodate developers who may need **additional time to update their existing apps on the App Store**, the deadline for adhering to the requirements below has been extended to June 30, 2020.
>
> - Apps for iPhone or iPad **must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later** and use an Xcode storyboard to provide the app’s launch screen.

I have an app that I have no need to update right now (it was built with iOS 12 SDK).

So what does that last message mean? Do I need to re-build and re-submit just to meet this requirement in order to keep my app on the App Store? Or do they only mean this is required for new app updates submitted?

Comment: I read this as a new requirement. For many years now, apple has been evaluating apps already in the store and removing them when they don't meet requirements. The removal will not happen instantly, usually you get about a month's notice that the app doesn't meet requirements, and you can argue for an extension in the resolution center if you need to. (May not help tho.)

Comment: Also worth noting that they will almost certainly not remove all the non-compliant apps at once, even though they could probably do so if they chose to. I'm sure they have procedures (which we do not have visibility into) for how they do this.

Comment: A side for anyone like me, this popped up randomly in November 2020. I am all updated, just had to restart XCode and it worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Do I need to re-build and re-submit just to meet this requirement in order to keep my app on the App Store?

**No**. If you have no pressing need to release an app update, no action is needed on your part. The message applies only to developers who are either working on releasing a new app or an update to an existing app on the App Store.

> Or do they only mean this is required for new app updates submitted?

**Yes**.

The message simply means that any developer looking to either release a new app or an update to an existing app on the App Store will have to build it using iOS 13 SDK starting April 30, 2020. The last message mean that the said deadline has been extended to June 30, 2020.

You can still release a new app or an update using iOS 12 SDK till June 29, 2020. (In your case, as your last release is built using iOS 12 SDK.)

Again, no action is needed on your part if there's no change in your app. Also, you can still release an app update, till June 29, 2020, using iOS 12 SDK.

Even starting June 30, 2020, no action would be required from your part. But past that point, any update that you wish to submit would be required to be built using iOS 13 SDK (Xcode 11).

Comment: why are you so sure? I hope you are right! :o) I had to update a lot of apps

Comment: @Chakalaka I sincerely hope I am right. I can say that with a certain level of confidence after having followed such updates from Apple for over a decade now.

Comment: I don't think we know this. I'll elaborate in a comment on the question.

Comment: May i know this also affect Enterprise app distribution as well?

Comment: @KangChianGim If your IT team is handling the enterprise app distribution internally, meaning the app isn't submitted to App Store Connect and doesn't go through the App Store Review Team, the deadline doesn't apply. As long as you can build an IPA, you can distribute it internally.

Comment: Thanks! @NimeshNeema

Comment: What if nit updated the app with iOS13 SDK?. Anyone please answer this.

Comment: Any links to actual Apple docs that state this? Wanting to confirm with an official source.

Comment: @steventnorris While I understand your concern to confirm by reading an official document, I am afraid there isn't any (at least as far as I am aware of). This has pretty much been a standard convention with app publishing, and humbly speaking, I have been doing it for a decade now. I'd certainly update the answer if I can find one :)