# Prerequisities for admob ads in iOS devices issue

Tags: ios, admob

Google mentions the following prerequisities for admob to work based on this page https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start

Prerequisites
Use Xcode 11 or higher
Target iOS 9.0 or higher
Recommended: Create an AdMob account and register an app.

The thing is that I do not have a newer macbook to update to latest macos to install xcode 11. So my question is, will the admob ads work on xcode 8.3.3 macos high sierra? I have a device with iOS 9.0 so this would not be an issue. Any help?

Comment: technically you should be able to use older version of xcode. However you will not be able to submit your app to itunes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963113/ios-13-sdk-deadline-confusion-for-existing-released-apps

Comment: I see thanks for the reply the answer accepted in the other question You have mentioned clarifies the prerequisites of this question. So i have to update to Xcode 11.